# Can a TFS2015 script only Deploy (and not Build)?

Tags: tfs, deployment, build, tfs-2015

I am new to the world of scripting with TFS2015.  I created a script that builds all of the projects within my solution (it is a rather large solution) and puts it out in a shared folder (where each project has its own subfolder).

I would like to create a separate script for each project that simply copies the `bin` folder from the shared and pastes it out on my Test environment.  I rarely need to deploy everything, so the idea is one build...multiple deploys.

However, when I run my deploy script using the `Copy Files` step it is doing another build.  Although it copies the files that I expect, it is after a full build that creates the folder structure for the build.

Am I able to make the `Copy Files` step NOT do a Build?

Here is the steps that my script is curently doing:

[image]

As  you can see, there is only one step (Copy Files) but it still does the `Get sources` and copies everything into a new folder on the build box like so (where the number keeps incrementing up with each run of the script):

[image]

I just want to copy the files from the `Source` to the `Target` and not do a build or `Get Sources`.

Comment: Copy files task will not build at all.! Could you share your build definition, so that we can find out which goes wrong?

Comment: Can you share the script you are using? If you only want to copy files from one directory to another in your own script, just use Copy files task instead. Besides, for TFS build/deploy, you can achieve lots of thing by using build/release tasks instead of writing script by yourself.

Comment: @Jayendran Sorry, I was out of town over the weekend.  I updated my question to show the build definition.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Sorry, I was out of town over the weekend.  I updated my question to show the build definition.

Comment: Not sure if TFS 2015 had this, but in recent versions the "Repository" settings have a "Don't sync sources" option. A better alternative would be to use *Release Management*, which is meant to so deployments.

Comment: @jessehouwing TFS2015 must not have that setting.  I am not seeing it under the Repository settings.  I also do not have a `Release Management` step in my list of available tasks.

Comment: Release Management was introduced in TFS 2015 update 2. You could configure a build that is linked to a very small Git repository or an empty TFVC repository or folder. That would at least make it small.

Comment: @jessehouwing We must be using plain old TFS2015 without update2. 
 Wonderful, lol.  Based on your suggestion with a Git repo, are you saying that I always have to `Get Source` when doing a `Copy Files`?  I have no way of doing JUST a copy/paste of some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're still on TFS 2015 RTM or Update 1. Which is already pretty old technology if you compare it to the lifetime of the new build system which was introduced with this version.

[TFS 2015 update 2 has introduced a similar system to the Build pipelines to orchestrate Releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2015-update2-vs#newrmtfs). This doesn't require you to map any workspaces or git repositories and can act on the artefacts of your builds or simply on the contents of file shares.

[image]

It makes sense that a Build has to build something and in order to build something, it has to get the things to build. If you're actually not building something, then you're probably deploying or releasing or packaging something else. Hence the distinction between Build and Release pipelines.

TFS 2017+ has an option to [disable the syncing of sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/repository?view=vsts). Primarily to allow people to get the sources themselves in creative ways (e.g. a custom powershell script that invokes git.exe).

My primary advice would be to upgrade to [TFS 2018 update 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update3) or at least [TFS 2017 update 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-update3), worst case [TFS 2015 update 4.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2015-update4-vs). The fact that [versions older than update 2015.4.1 have a known XSS scripting security bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2018/03/02/13895/) may be reason enough to convince your organisation to perform this update.

Barring that option you're left with one solution:

Link your build definition either to a git repository with only a single commit (If I remember correctly the 2015 agent still crashes when syncing an empty Git repo) or link it to a TFVC repository and set the workspace settings to cloak everything. This essentially causes the build to sync an empty folder, which it can cache, before calling your powershell script.

Comment: I looked up the version number of TFS2015 that we are using (14.102.25423.0).  Which means that we are using TFS2015 Update3.  Unfortunately, the TFS server is handled by another team which will never get updated (hence why it is so old).

Comment: Maybe I am looking in the wrong location?  I am adding a new step, under the 'All' tab I am seeing stuff like `Copy Files`, `Powershell`, etc etc.  There is nothing called `Release` in this list.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, I now see the `Release` tab that you are looking at.  Thank you for your patience.  I will take a look into this tab as I have never used it before :-)